# rendering to string with relative path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip

I have a problem with my downloading zip. It works fine, but the build method renders html file and gives away links like that:

```
 <script src="/assets/impress.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Whereas I would need it to be relative path:

```
<script src="assets/impress.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can I remove '/' on the beginning of the links using ruby. Here is the code section using zip gem.

```
  def download
    build
    data = render_to_string :build
    js_path = Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "javascripts")

    zip = Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer do |out|
      out.put_next_entry("index.html")
      out.write(data)

      out.put_next_entry("assets/impress.js")
      out.write File.read js_path.join("impress.js")

    end
    zip.rewind
    binary_zip = zip.sysread

    send_data(binary_zip, {filename: "impress.zip"})
  end
```

Comment: Can you include the code from the build method you are calling?

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace '/' on the beginning of the link with './'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089455/replace-on-the-beginning-of-the-link-with)

Comment: here is the code form build method: https://github.com/lipenco/impress.js-app/blob/master/app/controllers/presentation_controller.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for your relative paths problem. If you are generating the content of `index.html` file you can replace the paths in generated content.

There is a line [#48](https://github.com/lipenco/impress.js-app/blob/master/app/controllers/presentation_controller.rb#L48) where you `data = render_to_string :build`. In line below it just replace all `"/"` starting paths with relative version (`"./"`), like this:

```
data.gsub!('<script type="text/javascript" src="/', '<script type="text/javascript" src="./')
data.gsub!('<link href="/', '<link href="./')
```

And then you should have it working. If you want to do it also for images just implement similar replace rules.